# How to set SHELL=/bin/bash globally for cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron, environment-variables

With `BASH_ENV` assigned in `/etc/environment` I noticed that it doesn't affect cron jobs.

I figured out that having `SHELL=/bin/bash` in a users' crontab does the trick! Yes! If I simply add (to the crontab):

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

... it works. I **can** go in as root and do a simple:

```
sed -i 1iSHELL=/bin/bash /var/spool/cron/*
```

However, I'd like to have this setting global (or the default).

Is it possible to set default cron SHELL as bash?

I've already tried the following, none of which did the trick:

- Adding the line in `/etc/crontab` [effects only the /etc/crontab itself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306494/etc-crontab-shell-setting-does-not-have-effect-on-actual-cron-job) not all users
- Adding to `/etc/sysconfig/crond` and restart the cron
- Adding to `/etc/environment` and cron restart
- Added `session required pam_env.so readenv=1` to `/etc/pam.d/crond` and restart cron
- Added line to `/etc/default/cron` and another restart

How to set default cron SHELL as bash?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to set a global default shell for cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is that if you are running shell scripts from crontab, then you can put this at the top of the script.

> #!/bin/bash -l

This will make it act like a login shell.

Comment: Neat suggestion/workaround, but this would require me now to change all scripts (and I also wonder if there's any downside with the `-l` and if/why **not** to do it) . I know I can just add to all crontabs **like this:** `sed -i 1iSHELL=/bin/bash /var/spool/cron/*` as `root`, but I'm hoping for something more neat.